# which data structure is good for temporary big binary data storage?

Tags: c#, .net

Plan to have a data structure to store temporary binary data in the memory for analysis.

The max size of the data will be about `10MB`.

data will be added at the end `408 bytes` at a time.

no search, retrieve operations on those temporary binary data.

data will be wipe out and the storage will be reused for next analysis.

questions:

1. which structure is good for this purpose? `byte[10MB], List<bytes>(10MB), List<MyStruct>(24000), or ...?`
2. how to quickly wipe out the data (not List.Clear(), just set the value to 0) for List or array?
3. If I say `List.Clear(),` the memory for this `List` will shrink or the capacity (memory) of the List is still there and no memory allocation when I call `List.AddRange()` after the `Clear()?`
4. List.Insert() will make the List larger or it just replace the existing item?

Comment: What kind of "retrieve operations" are we talking about? Processing individual blocks of 408 bytes?

Comment: means take data out from the middle of the data

Comment: But how do you intend to do that? Can you describe what kind of "analysis" you're going to do?

Comment: what kind of analysis is not important for now. it may get all data and pass to thirdparty application, then store the data into database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is usually the same size, and always under a certain size, use a byte array.

Create a byte[], and a int that lets you know where the end of the "full" part of that buffer stops and the "free" part starts.  You never need to clear it; just overwrite what was there.  The only problem with this is if your data is sometimes 100 kb, sometimes 10 MB, and sometimes a bit larger than you originally planned for.

List will be slower to use and larger in memory, although they handle various sizes of data out of the box.

Comment: If it's always in the same ballpark, this still works pretty well; if you're always looking at 5-10 megs, and never more than 10 megs, give yourself a 10 meg array buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to describe what you are doing more to give better answers but it sounds like you are worried about efficiency/perf so

1. byte[]
2. no need to clear the array, just keep track of where the 'end' of your current cycle is
3. n/a
4. n/a

Answer (score 0):

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    Do stuff
} // the using ensures proper simple disposal occurs here so you don't have to worry about cleaning up.
```

Comment: There is a certain logic to the rule: If it implements IDisposable, Dispose of it. But sometimes we are allowed to exercise our brains. The purpose of IDisposable is to relinquish *external* resources long before the GC gets around to releasing the memory. What external resources do you imagine that a MemoryStream has? I'll give you the answer: None.